# I can't link css files to html is not working on eclipse

Tags: html, css, eclipse, jsp

I downloaded some css template from the web, copied the folders containing the css files and pasted them in my project, i used their html code as well in order to test the page on the server. It just doesnt work and i went through all the steps on the internet to link css to html.

The css folder is inside WEB-INF, the jsp pages are inside web content, i can't yet post an image on the site so i'll hope you can picture the structure.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/WEB-INF/css/animate.css" type = "text/css"/>
```

this is the link syntax i'm using copied from stackoverflow.com and even if i include the project name in the path, it still doesn't work.

Is the folder structures wrong ? or something with the link syntax ?

any help appreciated

Comment: What about just `href="/css/animate.css"`?

Comment: Do you have the html page in the same level as the WEB-INF folder? If so try removing the leading "/" `<link rel="stylesheet" href="WEB-INF/css/animate.css" type = "text/css"/>` If not specify the folder from which your html file lies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Think you have just to be simple and link your css like this:

This work in HTML, PHP

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/animate.css" />
```

This is for ASP.NET

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" runat="server" href="css/animate.css" />
```

I Hope it help!

Answer (score 2):

change

```
 href="/WEB-INF/css/animate.css"
```

to

```
 href="/css/animate.css"
```

You don't need to write that... css, pages and images are usually put into the webcontent folder (as per practice).